# Weight for orthogonal eigenfunctions

Tags: orthogonality, eigenfunctions

Is there an easy way to find the weight to make eigenfunctions orthogonal? (by hand and with an "easy" logic process, no numerical method type stuff)

Let's move on to an example taken from solving Laplace's equation on a ring sector, at some point we get (with $E_n$ being constants):
[image]

Is there an easy way to find that those functions are orthogonal with weight functions $\frac{1}{r}$?

So that we can do:
[image]

Thus allowing us to go further in the solving.

So:

- Main question: is there a way to find the weight function of this example?  (assuming a case where we have to find it and we don't know it).
- If so, is there anything similar that can be applied to find the weight function in general? or in some specific useful cases? (If that last question covers too much, it can be ignored).

Comment: You ask several questions; are you asking for how to find the weight function in general? Or just in this example, how to show that it is true?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my message. 1. I know that the example is true, I don't need to prove it 2. I'm mainly trying to find the way to get the weight function of this specific example (most important question) 3. Is there anything similar that can be applied in general? or in some specific useful cases? If that last question covers too much, it can be ignored.

Comment: If the eigenfunctions are associated with an ODE that can be coerced into Sturm-Liouville form you can read off the weight function from it.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. I'm stuck on that transformation for my actual problem though. I posted the PDE I am trying to get the Sturm Liouville form of in a new post:: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612061/transforming-a-pde-into-sturm-liouville-form-separation-of-variables-methods