# Transforming a PDE into Sturm Liouville form (separation of variables methods)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Is there a way to transform the PDE:
[image]

Into a Sturm-Liouville problem with a clearly identified weight function, thanks to the method of separation of variables? I am stuck on this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to separate variables? What is the region? Is it $0 \le r < \infty$ and $0 \le \theta\le 2\pi$, or some subset of that?

Comment: It was the case of a sector ring I was facing. But does it matter to find the Sturm Liouville problem? I just managed to find the SL form and it is (rR')' +(1/r)k²R = 0 , so with weight function 1/r ! Thank you for trying to help

Comment: I'm glad you found what you wanted. To me, a well-posed Sturm-Liouville equation also requires endpoint conditions such as periodicity, boundedness, or homogeneous endpoint conditions, for example. That's why I was asking for more details.

Comment: I thought you meant it could change de weight function. But with the meaning you just explained, you are totally right. Indeed my problem had such homogeneous conditions.